# Multiplying the probability matrix, incorrect values on a large number of iterations

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, precision, matrix-multiplication

I have the next code, which multiplies the *probability matrix* `p` the certain number of times. For the first 50 iterations everything is ok, the sum of probabilities in each row is equal to `1`, but then I recieve the `sum > 1` and approximately on the 70th iteration I recieve infinity values. And I do not understand why.

The `sum` of probabilities in each row must be equal to `1`. This is the classic *Markov's chain model*. And regardless of num of multiplications you must receive the `sum = 1` in each row. I suppose there is a problem in a floating-point calculation.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        double[][] p = {
                {0.02, 0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
                {0.02, 0.02, 0.38, 0.38, 0.2},
                {0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.92, 0.02},
                {0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
                {0.47, 0.02, 0.47, 0.02, 0.02}};

        for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
            p = multiply(p, p);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%9.4f", p[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static double[][] multiply(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
        int w = a[0].length;
        int l = b.length;
        if (w != l) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of columns " +
                    "in the first matrix must be equal to the number " +
                    "of rows in second matrix!" + w + " " + l);
        }

        double[][] result = new double[a.length][b[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
                    result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

/*
output for the trials = 30:
   0,2730   0,2657   0,1462   0,2472   0,0678
   0,2730   0,2657   0,1462   0,2472   0,0678
   0,2730   0,2657   0,1462   0,2472   0,0678
   0,2730   0,2657   0,1462   0,2472   0,0678
   0,2730   0,2657   0,1462   0,2472   0,0678

output for the trials = 45:
   0,2732   0,2659   0,1463   0,2474   0,0679
   0,2732   0,2659   0,1463   0,2474   0,0679
   0,2732   0,2659   0,1463   0,2474   0,0679
   0,2732   0,2659   0,1463   0,2474   0,0679
   0,2732   0,2659   0,1463   0,2474   0,0679

output for the trials = 55:
   0,5183   0,5044   0,2775   0,4693   0,1288
   0,5183   0,5044   0,2775   0,4693   0,1288
   0,5183   0,5044   0,2775   0,4693   0,1288
   0,5183   0,5044   0,2775   0,4693   0,1288
   0,5183   0,5044   0,2775   0,4693   0,1288

output for the trials = 70:
 Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity
 Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity
 Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity
 Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity
 Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity Infinity
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

Floating point calculations, especially those with large fractional parts, are associated with rounding in most cases. The question is *how* and *what* to round?

#### Floating point matrix multiplication

You can use *matrix multiplication* with [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `double`. In this case, the 34-digit [`DECIMAL128`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL128) format can be enough for the first 151 trials. Result can be represented using *scientific notation* with an exponent if needed.

To convert `double` to `BigDecimal` use the [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)) method and don't use the constructor [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)), otherwise you can get *unpredictable* appendix to each number. I guess, this is the main mistake in the calculations with `double`.

In this case, starting from the 5th trial the row sums become less than `1` because of rounding, and then they become even less, and after the 151st trial you will get an [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) *underflow*, because the numbers are getting smaller than the rounding bounds.

#### Spherical horse in vacuum

For *more precise* calculations you can use [`UNLIMITED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#UNLIMITED) precision arithmetic. In this case, the sums of the rows are *stably equal to `1`* on each iteration, but it thinks *too long*, even in [`parallel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#parallel--) mode, so I stopped at the 20th trial with such a `MathContext`. It takes about *five minutes* to calculate the 20th iteration, that's enough for me. The time for further trials grows in *geometric progression* with an approximate *common ratio* of `3`, but it continues to work without a memory leaks. I hope this is the case, so I think it might take approximately more than *a year* to calculate the first 30 trials...

#### Working code

The first 151 trials in 34-digit `DECIMAL128` format, every tenth trial is printed using *scientific notation*. You can convert these values to [`doubleValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()) and round the row sums back to `1` until the 65th trial, but in this case you will get `0.0` after the 128th trial:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int d = 5; // dimensions
    int trials = 151;

    // rules for numerical operators
    MathContext mc = MathContext.DECIMAL128;

    BigDecimal[][] p = toBigDecimal(new double[][]{
            {0.02, 0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
            {0.02, 0.02, 0.38, 0.38, 0.2},
            {0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.92, 0.02},
            {0.92, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02},
            {0.47, 0.02, 0.47, 0.02, 0.02}});

    // matrix multiplication
    for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        p = parallelMatrixMultiplication(mc, d, d, d, p, p);
        // print every tenth trial
        if (t % 10 == 0)
            outputMatrix(p, t, time);
    }
}
```

```java
static void outputMatrix(BigDecimal[][] matrix, int t, long time) {
    System.out.println("trial: " + t);
    for (BigDecimal[] row : matrix) {
        BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
        for (BigDecimal element : row) {
            sum = sum.add(element);
            // string representation of this element, using
            // scientific notation with an exponent if needed
            System.out.print(element.toString() + " ");
        }
        // sum of the row in the same format
        System.out.println("|| " + sum.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}
```

```java
static BigDecimal[][] toBigDecimal(double[][] matrix) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrix)
            .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                    .mapToObj(BigDecimal::valueOf)
                    .toArray(BigDecimal[]::new))
            .toArray(BigDecimal[][]::new);
}
```

```java
/**
 * Parallel Matrix multiplication
 *
 * @param mc rules for numerical operators
 * @param m  rows of 'a' matrix
 * @param n  columns of 'a' matrix
 *           and rows of 'b' matrix
 * @param p  columns of 'b' matrix
 * @param a  first matrix 'm×n'
 * @param b  second matrix 'n×p'
 * @return result matrix 'm×p'
 */
static BigDecimal[][] parallelMatrixMultiplication(
        MathContext mc, int m, int n, int p,
        BigDecimal[][] a, BigDecimal[][] b) {
    return IntStream.range(0, m)
            .parallel()
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, p)
                    .mapToObj(j -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                            .mapToObj(k -> a[i][k].multiply(b[k][j], mc))
                            .reduce((bd1, bd2) -> bd1.add(bd2, mc))
                            .orElse(new BigDecimal("0")))
                    .toArray(BigDecimal[]::new))
            .toArray(BigDecimal[][]::new);
}
```

Output:

```
trial: 0
0.0470 0.0380 0.3602 0.3692 0.1856 || 1.0000
0.4520 0.0380 0.1172 0.3692 0.0236 || 1.0000
0.8570 0.0380 0.0362 0.0452 0.0236 || 1.0000
0.0470 0.8480 0.0362 0.0452 0.0236 || 1.0000
0.0470 0.4430 0.0362 0.4502 0.0236 || 1.0000
time: 48
trial: 10
0.2730292887828770329701825732219565 0.2657263599045893296731643158997608 0.1461853247179238943858654633117944 0.2472282818117836636296180707045289 0.06783074478282607934116957686195689 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999999749
0.2730292887828770329701825732219565 0.2657263599045893296731643158997608 0.1461853247179238943858654633117944 0.2472282818117836636296180707045289 0.06783074478282607934116957686195689 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999999749
0.2730292887828770329701825732219566 0.2657263599045893296731643158997610 0.1461853247179238943858654633117944 0.2472282818117836636296180707045290 0.06783074478282607934116957686195692 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999999792
0.2730292887828770329701825732219565 0.2657263599045893296731643158997607 0.1461853247179238943858654633117943 0.2472282818117836636296180707045288 0.06783074478282607934116957686195687 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999999717
0.2730292887828770329701825732219565 0.2657263599045893296731643158997608 0.1461853247179238943858654633117944 0.2472282818117836636296180707045289 0.06783074478282607934116957686195689 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999999749
time: 11
trial: 20
0.2730292887828770329701825732212719 0.2657263599045893296731643158990943 0.1461853247179238943858654633114277 0.2472282818117836636296180707039089 0.06783074478282607934116957686178676 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999748956
0.2730292887828770329701825732212719 0.2657263599045893296731643158990943 0.1461853247179238943858654633114277 0.2472282818117836636296180707039089 0.06783074478282607934116957686178676 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999748956
0.2730292887828770329701825732212719 0.2657263599045893296731643158990943 0.1461853247179238943858654633114277 0.2472282818117836636296180707039089 0.06783074478282607934116957686178676 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999748956
0.2730292887828770329701825732212715 0.2657263599045893296731643158990941 0.1461853247179238943858654633114276 0.2472282818117836636296180707039086 0.06783074478282607934116957686178666 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999748846
0.2730292887828770329701825732212719 0.2657263599045893296731643158990943 0.1461853247179238943858654633114277 0.2472282818117836636296180707039089 0.06783074478282607934116957686178676 || 0.99999999999999999999999999999748956
time: 9
trial: 30
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
0.2730292887828770329701825725200011 0.2657263599045893296731643152165811 0.1461853247179238943858654629359533 0.2472282818117836636296180700689076 0.06783074478282607934116957668756474 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900784
0.2730292887828770329701825725200014 0.2657263599045893296731643152165814 0.1461853247179238943858654629359535 0.2472282818117836636296180700689079 0.06783074478282607934116957668756482 || 0.99999999999999999999999999742900902
time: 10
trial: 40
0.2730292887828770329701818544190935 0.2657263599045893296731636163232827 0.1461853247179238943858650784504105 0.2472282818117836636296174198278500 0.06783074478282607934116939828428938 || 0.99999999999999999999999736730492608
0.2730292887828770329701818544190935 0.2657263599045893296731636163232827 0.1461853247179238943858650784504105 0.2472282818117836636296174198278500 0.06783074478282607934116939828428938 || 0.99999999999999999999999736730492608
0.2730292887828770329701818544190935 0.2657263599045893296731636163232827 0.1461853247179238943858650784504105 0.2472282818117836636296174198278500 0.06783074478282607934116939828428938 || 0.99999999999999999999999736730492608
0.2730292887828770329701818544190931 0.2657263599045893296731636163232822 0.1461853247179238943858650784504101 0.2472282818117836636296174198278496 0.06783074478282607934116939828428926 || 0.99999999999999999999999736730492426
0.2730292887828770329701818544190935 0.2657263599045893296731636163232827 0.1461853247179238943858650784504105 0.2472282818117836636296174198278500 0.06783074478282607934116939828428938 || 0.99999999999999999999999736730492608
time: 8
trial: 50
0.2730292887828770329694465190894863 0.2657263599045893296724479495854144 0.1461853247179238943854713652542387 0.2472282818117836636289515729844414 0.06783074478282607934098671333025123 || 0.99999999999999999999730412024383203
0.2730292887828770329694465190894863 0.2657263599045893296724479495854144 0.1461853247179238943854713652542387 0.2472282818117836636289515729844414 0.06783074478282607934098671333025123 || 0.99999999999999999999730412024383203
0.2730292887828770329694465190894863 0.2657263599045893296724479495854144 0.1461853247179238943854713652542387 0.2472282818117836636289515729844414 0.06783074478282607934098671333025123 || 0.99999999999999999999730412024383203
0.2730292887828770329694465190894859 0.2657263599045893296724479495854140 0.1461853247179238943854713652542385 0.2472282818117836636289515729844411 0.06783074478282607934098671333025115 || 0.99999999999999999999730412024383065
0.2730292887828770329694465190894863 0.2657263599045893296724479495854144 0.1461853247179238943854713652542387 0.2472282818117836636289515729844414 0.06783074478282607934098671333025123 || 0.99999999999999999999730412024383203
time: 9
trial: 60
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
0.2730292887828770322164631415718818 0.2657263599045893289396052100083676 0.1461853247179238939823090523745172 0.2472282818117836629471244053337525 0.06783074478282607915391732039518012 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968369922
0.2730292887828770322164631415718825 0.2657263599045893289396052100083683 0.1461853247179238939823090523745175 0.2472282818117836629471244053337530 0.06783074478282607915391732039518029 || 0.99999999999999999723941912968370159
time: 9
trial: 70
0.2730292887828762611614845635464324 0.2657263599045885785086398831140649 0.1461853247179234811441006635406023 0.2472282818117829647561047310298819 0.06783074478282588759485895488280742 || 0.99999999999999717316518879611378892
0.2730292887828762611614845635464324 0.2657263599045885785086398831140649 0.1461853247179234811441006635406023 0.2472282818117829647561047310298819 0.06783074478282588759485895488280742 || 0.99999999999999717316518879611378892
0.2730292887828762611614845635464324 0.2657263599045885785086398831140649 0.1461853247179234811441006635406023 0.2472282818117829647561047310298819 0.06783074478282588759485895488280742 || 0.99999999999999717316518879611378892
0.2730292887828762611614845635464319 0.2657263599045885785086398831140646 0.1461853247179234811441006635406021 0.2472282818117829647561047310298813 0.06783074478282588759485895488280730 || 0.99999999999999717316518879611378720
0.2730292887828762611614845635464324 0.2657263599045885785086398831140649 0.1461853247179234811441006635406023 0.2472282818117829647561047310298819 0.06783074478282588759485895488280742 || 0.99999999999999717316518879611378892
time: 8
trial: 80
0.2730292887820867008634218082462759 0.2657263599038201372001462555418668 0.1461853247175007348187111094682799 0.2472282818110680171519592786367428 0.06783074478262973111909295411775437 || 0.99999999999710532115333140601091977
0.2730292887820867008634218082462759 0.2657263599038201372001462555418668 0.1461853247175007348187111094682799 0.2472282818110680171519592786367428 0.06783074478262973111909295411775437 || 0.99999999999710532115333140601091977
0.2730292887820867008634218082462759 0.2657263599038201372001462555418668 0.1461853247175007348187111094682799 0.2472282818110680171519592786367428 0.06783074478262973111909295411775437 || 0.99999999999710532115333140601091977
0.2730292887820867008634218082462755 0.2657263599038201372001462555418664 0.1461853247175007348187111094682796 0.2472282818110680171519592786367424 0.06783074478262973111909295411775427 || 0.99999999999710532115333140601091817
0.2730292887820867008634218082462759 0.2657263599038201372001462555418668 0.1461853247175007348187111094682799 0.2472282818110680171519592786367428 0.06783074478262973111909295411775437 || 0.99999999999710532115333140601091977
time: 12
trial: 90
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
0.2730292879735769568454317780258548 0.2657263591169362384688919123320136 0.1461853242846084982613861358960977 0.2472282810789616715920519228547582 0.06783074458176550023240385632850703 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723133
0.2730292879735769568454317780258554 0.2657263591169362384688919123320142 0.1461853242846084982613861358960980 0.2472282810789616715920519228547587 0.06783074458176550023240385632850718 || 0.99999999703584886540016560543723348
time: 8
trial: 100
0.2730284600608555597809096423856914 0.2657255533490468070347525429793999 0.1461848810036310065886299754607182 0.2472275314032015596942117582195087 0.06783053889710522849818932256856966 || 0.99999696471384016159669324161388786
0.2730284600608555597809096423856914 0.2657255533490468070347525429793999 0.1461848810036310065886299754607182 0.2472275314032015596942117582195087 0.06783053889710522849818932256856966 || 0.99999696471384016159669324161388786
0.2730284600608555597809096423856914 0.2657255533490468070347525429793999 0.1461848810036310065886299754607182 0.2472275314032015596942117582195087 0.06783053889710522849818932256856966 || 0.99999696471384016159669324161388786
0.2730284600608555597809096423856910 0.2657255533490468070347525429793995 0.1461848810036310065886299754607179 0.2472275314032015596942117582195082 0.06783053889710522849818932256856957 || 0.99999696471384016159669324161388617
0.2730284600608555597809096423856914 0.2657255533490468070347525429793999 0.1461848810036310065886299754607182 0.2472275314032015596942117582195087 0.06783053889710522849818932256856966 || 0.99999696471384016159669324161388786
time: 12
trial: 110
0.2721819935822030657304032357038538 0.2649017279742810454592283638310650 0.1457316659745904561852246134110141 0.2464610551981708732338898147466929 0.06762024478566887448452655718718783 || 0.99689668751491431509327258487981363
0.2721819935822030657304032357038538 0.2649017279742810454592283638310650 0.1457316659745904561852246134110141 0.2464610551981708732338898147466929 0.06762024478566887448452655718718783 || 0.99689668751491431509327258487981363
0.2721819935822030657304032357038538 0.2649017279742810454592283638310650 0.1457316659745904561852246134110141 0.2464610551981708732338898147466929 0.06762024478566887448452655718718783 || 0.99689668751491431509327258487981363
0.2721819935822030657304032357038534 0.2649017279742810454592283638310646 0.1457316659745904561852246134110139 0.2464610551981708732338898147466923 0.06762024478566887448452655718718771 || 0.99689668751491431509327258487981191
0.2721819935822030657304032357038538 0.2649017279742810454592283638310650 0.1457316659745904561852246134110141 0.2464610551981708732338898147466929 0.06762024478566887448452655718718783 || 0.99689668751491431509327258487981363
time: 8
trial: 120
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
0.01132311287302140636187625536070982 0.01102024467759399595775450897719917 0.006062620386037311053865263230157291 0.01025308952324214872533623929149360 0.002813087133841649504461690768456168 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016049
0.01132311287302140636187625536070984 0.01102024467759399595775450897719919 0.006062620386037311053865263230157305 0.01025308952324214872533623929149362 0.002813087133841649504461690768456174 || 0.041472154593736511603293957628016129
time: 8
trial: 130
1.044639308739343328720850715228411E-1416 1.016697520482136028467012050376325E-1416 5.593207133268761858504096038885519E-1417 9.459218919844845701317393883059301E-1417 2.595276963035115177423085757384926E-1417 || 3.8261071308363516309123203335377106E-1416
1.044639308739343328720850715228411E-1416 1.016697520482136028467012050376325E-1416 5.593207133268761858504096038885519E-1417 9.459218919844845701317393883059301E-1417 2.595276963035115177423085757384926E-1417 || 3.8261071308363516309123203335377106E-1416
1.044639308739343328720850715228411E-1416 1.016697520482136028467012050376325E-1416 5.593207133268761858504096038885519E-1417 9.459218919844845701317393883059301E-1417 2.595276963035115177423085757384926E-1417 || 3.8261071308363516309123203335377106E-1416
1.044639308739343328720850715228409E-1416 1.016697520482136028467012050376324E-1416 5.593207133268761858504096038885513E-1417 9.459218919844845701317393883059288E-1417 2.595276963035115177423085757384923E-1417 || 3.8261071308363516309123203335377054E-1416
1.044639308739343328720850715228411E-1416 1.016697520482136028467012050376325E-1416 5.593207133268761858504096038885519E-1417 9.459218919844845701317393883059301E-1417 2.595276963035115177423085757384926E-1417 || 3.8261071308363516309123203335377106E-1416
time: 8
trial: 140
1.511841812795049791388737404792298E-1449388 1.471403392128599201290355981548488E-1449388 8.094702488176411118777608478542366E-1449389 1.368974205715227102195005233661688E-1449388 3.755983711962022452727563939141449E-1449389 || 5.5372880306527194520246158617708555E-1449388
1.511841812795049791388737404792298E-1449388 1.471403392128599201290355981548488E-1449388 8.094702488176411118777608478542366E-1449389 1.368974205715227102195005233661688E-1449388 3.755983711962022452727563939141449E-1449389 || 5.5372880306527194520246158617708555E-1449388
1.511841812795049791388737404792298E-1449388 1.471403392128599201290355981548488E-1449388 8.094702488176411118777608478542366E-1449389 1.368974205715227102195005233661688E-1449388 3.755983711962022452727563939141449E-1449389 || 5.5372880306527194520246158617708555E-1449388
1.511841812795049791388737404792296E-1449388 1.471403392128599201290355981548485E-1449388 8.094702488176411118777608478542352E-1449389 1.368974205715227102195005233661686E-1449388 3.755983711962022452727563939141443E-1449389 || 5.5372880306527194520246158617708465E-1449388
1.511841812795049791388737404792298E-1449388 1.471403392128599201290355981548488E-1449388 8.094702488176411118777608478542366E-1449389 1.368974205715227102195005233661688E-1449388 3.755983711962022452727563939141449E-1449389 || 5.5372880306527194520246158617708555E-1449388
time: 7
trial: 150
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199849E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380794E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325263E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190750E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494657E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461217E-1484172551
3.736410561203285932862056593199857E-1484172552 3.636469852606817133931883241380801E-1484172552 2.000548708909203057880207355325268E-1484172552 3.383323332480596714663696894190756E-1484172552 9.282649209930868784637712909494675E-1484172553 || 1.36850173761929897178016153750461495E-1484172551
time: 7
```

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

It's just math. At 57th iteration numbers exceed one and by multipling them together, they soon reach `Infinity`.

#### Longer version

You are multiplying and adding numbers that are `0 > num > 1`. With your data example it gets further away from 0 by multiplying (obviously) and getting closer to 1 by adding together. 
Your multiplications are mostly `0.92 * 0.38`, `0.47 * 0.92` etc. By adding them together  they are slowly getting closer to `1`. 
At 57th iteration some sums are exceeding `1`. After that the multiplication goes into a geometric progression and soon reaches `Infinity`. To better see the increase, try:

```java
public static double[][] multiply(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
    int w = a[0].length;
    int l = b.length;
    if (w != l) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of columns " +
                "in the first matrix must be equal to the number " +
                "of rows in second matrix!" + w + " " + l);
    }
    double[][] result = new double[a.length][b[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.println();
            //For debug
            //System.out.println("["+i+","+j+"]");
            for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
                //For debug
                //System.out.println("ADD: ["+i+","+k+"] * [" +k+","+j+"]");
                result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                c++;
            }
            //to see all cells of each iteration
            System.out.println(result[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //To see results of 1st cell of each iteration
    System.out.println("Counts: " + result[0][0]);
    return result;
}
```

#### Testing

Just simply change one of the array values from `0.02` to `0.5` or `1` and you will see that it reaches Infinity a lot sooner. Nothing weird about the code. Your test case was just a funny edge case that dances around `1` a lot.

#### Your outputs

Sometimes results with 40 or 42 iterations seemed identical. 
That was because the sum of columns was increasing so slowly that it wasn't visible in the first 4 positions behind point.